# Lego renew certificate hanging

Tags: lets-encrypt, certbot

I have some security certificates setup on multiple domain variants for my website. I have been following this guide on Bitnami:

https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/how-to/generate-install-lets-encrypt-ssl/#step-5-renew-the-lets-encrypt-certificate

I managed to create the certificates, but am now trying to renew them with this command:

```
sudo lego --email="name@email.com" --domains="mydomain.com" --domains="www.mydomain.com" --domains="mydomain.co.uk" --domains="www.mydomain.co.uk" --domains="mydomain.technology" --domains="www.mydomain.technology" --path="/etc/lego” renew
```

When I run this it just hangs. I get nothing back. Any ideas?

Comment: Your last `"` is wrong; Its probably waiting for the closing one

Comment: Yes!! Copy and paste gone bad! Thanks for spotting this.